# View.onMeasure() not called

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a very simple custom View with `onMeasure()` overriden. My `onMeasure()` decides the size according to the background Drawable. When the View is first created from xml everything works normally. But then I set a different background programatically, so the View should resize. The View has now a different background, but it doesn't resize and `onMeasure()` is not called.

I tried everything - `requestLayout()`, `forceLayout()`, `invalidate()`, `setLayoutParams()` - without any effect. What am I doing wrong? I just want my View to resize.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was calling setBackground() inside my View's onSizeChanged(). I refactored the code and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the obvious thing, i.e. how is your method declared?

If you did not add the `@override` annotation, add it, and see if your compiler tells you that it is not overriding anything. If so, check the name and method signature of [`onMeasure`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29).

Otherwise, make sure you understand when the `measure()` method is supposed to be called: [How Android draws Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

Comment: Yes, I'm using @Override - I see that my onMeasure() is called twice when my Activity is created. But it's not called after View.setBackground().

Comment: The article you linked suggests that requestLayout() should work, but it doesn't.